# How to sign custom messages vs hashes in MetaMask and recover them on-chain?

Tags: solidity

I have a dApp and I want to be able to present my users with a *custom message* to sign on MetaMask rather than just a hash string that I see other dApps do. I want to be able to recover this signature **on-chain**, so what's the best way to accomplish this?

I've been able to sign (and recover) hashed messages (see below), but am absolutely clueless how to do this with a long, custom message.

```
// Hashes a message and returns a signature
function signMessage(msg : string) { 
   let msgHash= ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(['string'],[msg]);      
   let sig = await this.mySigner.signMessage(ethers.utils.arrayify(hash));
   return sig;
}
```

to which I get the following prompt on Metamask:

[image]

But how do I present my users with a custom message AND be able to recover this entire message on-chain?

Comment: Did you try https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually searching for an implementation of the [EIP-712 specifications](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712), and you can find a complete and working example of how to sign typed data using the [official MetaMask E2E Test Dapp](https://metamask.github.io/test-dapp/).

The website above is the live version of the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/MetaMask/test-dapp) containing the end-to-end tests of all MetaMask features, including different types of signatures of typed data.

In particular, the code you are looking for is [at this line](https://github.com/MetaMask/test-dapp/blob/9a91811a03a447934db3a43563500d65cbd23bc8/src/index.js#L1311).

Below is the excerpt using some test data, but please refer to the repo for the most updated code.

```js
  signTypedDataV4.onclick = async () => {
    const networkId = parseInt(networkDiv.innerHTML, 10);
    const chainId = parseInt(chainIdDiv.innerHTML, 16) || networkId;
    const msgParams = {
      domain: {
        chainId: chainId.toString(),
        name: 'Ether Mail',
        verifyingContract: '0xCcCCccccCCCCcCCCCCCcCcCccCcCCCcCcccccccC',
        version: '1',
      },
      message: {
        contents: 'Hello, Bob!',
        from: {
          name: 'Cow',
          wallets: [
            '0xCD2a3d9F938E13CD947Ec05AbC7FE734Df8DD826',
            '0xDeaDbeefdEAdbeefdEadbEEFdeadbeEFdEaDbeeF',
          ],
        },
        to: [
          {
            name: 'Bob',
            wallets: [
              '0xbBbBBBBbbBBBbbbBbbBbbbbBBbBbbbbBbBbbBBbB',
              '0xB0BdaBea57B0BDABeA57b0bdABEA57b0BDabEa57',
              '0xB0B0b0b0b0b0B000000000000000000000000000',
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      primaryType: 'Mail',
      types: {
        EIP712Domain: [
          { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
          { name: 'version', type: 'string' },
          { name: 'chainId', type: 'uint256' },
          { name: 'verifyingContract', type: 'address' },
        ],
        Group: [
          { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
          { name: 'members', type: 'Person[]' },
        ],
        Mail: [
          { name: 'from', type: 'Person' },
          { name: 'to', type: 'Person[]' },
          { name: 'contents', type: 'string' },
        ],
        Person: [
          { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
          { name: 'wallets', type: 'address[]' },
        ],
      },
    };
    try {
      const from = accounts[0];
      const sign = await ethereum.request({
        method: 'eth_signTypedData_v4',
        params: [from, JSON.stringify(msgParams)],
      });
      signTypedDataV4Result.innerHTML = sign;
      signTypedDataV4Verify.disabled = false;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      signTypedDataV4Result.innerHTML = `Error: ${err.message}`;
    }
  };
```

On the MetaMask Docs website you can find all the [most updated information about signing data](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html).